# Download an Excel file from the latest email in Outlook inbox using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I receive a report once a week in the form of an Excel attachment (.xlsm). I need to access the latest email then download the Excel attachment within and save it to a specific path on my desktop.

The mailbox is called "ACBS MIS Reports" and the attachment is always called "Report on ACBS LC for AMLS - Month DD". It will always be the latest email (at top of mailbox) that I'm interested in.

This code returns the error message as written at the bottom of the code under "GetAttachments_err".

```
Sub GetAttachments()
' This Outlook macro checks a the Outlook Inbox for messages
' with attached files (of any type) and saves them to disk.
' NOTE: make sure the specified save folder exists before
' running the macro.

On Error GoTo GetAttachments_err

'Declare Variables

Dim ns As Namespace
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim Item As Object
Dim Atmt As Attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer
Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
i = 0

'Check Inbox for messages and exit if none found

If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, _
           "Nothing Found"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Check each message for attachments

For Each Item In Inbox.Items
'Save any attachments found
    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
    ' This path must exist! Change folder name as necessary.
        FileName = "C:\Users\jalanger\Desktop\Letters of Credit\Macro Work\Test" & Atmt.DisplayName
        Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
        i = i + 1
     Next Atmt
Next Item

' Show summary message
If i > 0 Then
    MsgBox "I found " & i & " attached files." _
    & vbCrLf & "I have saved them into the C:\Email Attachments folder." _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Have a nice day.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
Else
    MsgBox "I didn't find any attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
End If
'Clear memory
GetAttachments_exit:
Set Atmt = Nothing
Set Item = Nothing
Set ns = Nothing
Exit Sub

'Handle errors
GetAttachments_err:
MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
    & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
    & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
    & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
    & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
    , vbCritical, "Error!"
Resume GetAttachments_exit
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and which part your having trouble with?

Comment: I just added it to my question!

Comment: That's very verbose code that should be providing some indication of what's going on and the best you can describe is "can't seem to get this right".... Please explain the problem.

Comment: The problem is that when I run it, it returns the error message as written at the bottom of the code under "GetAttachments_err" and I don't know why

Comment: What following information do you see when you get the dialog box with "Please note and report the following information."? Edit the post with the response. Do not answer in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edit***  *The macro has been edited to run from Excel, instead of Outlook.  It uses early binding, so you'll need to set a reference to Outlook's object library (VBE >> Tools >> References >> and select Microsoft Outlook Object Library).*

The following macro first filters the items from the inbox based on the specified sender name, then sorts them by received time and in descending order, and then gets the first item from the filtered and sorted list.  Lastly, it saves the specified attachement, if it exists.  Note that if a file with the same name as the attachment already exists, the existing file will be over-written.  Change the save to folder, sender name, and attachment name, where indicated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetLatestReport()

    'Set a reference to Outlook's object library (Visual Basic >> Tools >> References >> check/select Microsoft Outlook Object Library)

    Dim outlookApp              As Outlook.Application
    Dim outlookInbox            As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim outlookRestrictItems    As Outlook.Items
    Dim outlookLatestItem       As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim outlookAttachment       As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim attachmentFound         As Boolean

    Const saveToFolder          As String = "C:\Users\Domenic\Desktop" 'change the save to folder accordingly
    Const senderName            As String = "SenderName" 'change the sender name accordingly
    Const attachmentName        As String = "AttachmentName" 'change the attachment name accordingly

    'Create an instance of Outlook
    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application

    'Get the inbox from Outlook
    Set outlookInbox = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    'Filter the items from the inbox based on the sender
    Set outlookRestrictItems = outlookInbox.Items.Restrict("[SenderName] = '" & senderName & "'")

    'Check whether any items were found
    If outlookRestrictItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No items were found from " & senderName & "!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Sort the filtered items by received time and in descending order
    outlookRestrictItems.Sort Property:="[ReceivedTime]", Descending:=True

    'Get the latest item from the filtered and sorted items
    Set outlookLatestItem = outlookRestrictItems(1)

    'Loop through each attachment from the latest item until specified file is found
    attachmentFound = False
    For Each outlookAttachment In outlookLatestItem.Attachments
        If Left(UCase(outlookAttachment.Filename), Len(attachmentName)) = UCase(attachmentName) Then
            outlookAttachment.SaveAsFile saveToFolder & "\" & outlookAttachment.DisplayName
            attachmentFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next outlookAttachment

    If attachmentFound Then
        MsgBox "The attachment was found and saved to '" & saveToFolder & "'!", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No attachment was found!", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I made the changes to sender name, attachment name, and save-to folder, but when I try to run it, it says "Object doesn't support this property or method" and highlights the line of code right under 'Get the inbox

Comment: I've been having this kind of problem with a lot of the codes I've been using to try to accomplish this and I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: Your original code was written for Outlook, and meant to be run from Outlook.  Hence my code was written for Outlook as well.  If you're running it from Excel, you'll get that error.  Are you running it from Excel?

Comment: If you want the code to run from Excel, it will need to be re-written.  Do you want to run it from Excel?

Comment: Yes, I want it to run from Excel. I'm writing in the Visual Basic Studio on Excel 2013

Comment: Thanks so much that worked! I guess my problem the whole time was what you said about the code being written to be executed in Outlook. That was awesome